# pipenv install giving Failed to load paths errors

Tags: python, pipenv, pipenv-install

I am running `pipenv install --dev` which is giving me the following errors

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (2df4c1)…
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /Users/XXXX/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-service-enGYxXYk/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /Users/XXXX/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-service-enGYxXYk/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /Users/XXXX/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-service-enGYxXYk/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I don't really want to change the command around I would rather solve the underlying issue as it is part of a package.json file in a project others are using rather than something i am just trying to run on my own machine..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove your Pipfile.lock and try rerunning pipenv install to rebuild your dependencies from your Pipfile. It is looking for a virtual environment that does not exist. By removing your Pipfile.lock, you force pipenv to create a new environment.

Comment: See also [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4086#issuecomment-907694695).

Answer (score 1):

I found the similar error on my ubuntu 20.04 like this :

```sh
frog@ocean:playground/demo-selenium $ pipenv install selenium
Installing selenium...
⠋ Installing...Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /home/frog/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-selenium-aj4lh7NL/bin/python: not found

Output: 
⠙ Installing selenium...Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /home/frog/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-selenium-aj4lh7NL/bin/python: not found

Output: 
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /home/frog/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-selenium-aj4lh7NL/bin/python: not found

Output: 
Error:  An error occurred while installing selenium!
Error text: 
/bin/sh: 1: /home/frog/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-selenium-aj4lh7NL/bin/pip: not found

✘ Installation Failed
```

How I solved is :
When I run `pipenv shell` to create a new virtual environment, just add option `--three` or `--two` to specified the python version.
Its because my linux doesn't install python 2.
Then i run again, and voile i could install selenium, finnaly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `pipenv --python 3.7`
and then `pipenv shell --three`

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in my Windows, what worked for me was running `pipenv --rm` and then `pipenv check`. Then I was able to run `pipenv install` without failure.